# Presto can search data from multiple hadoop cluster once time?

Tags: presto

I want to deploy multiple `hadoop` cluster,and the different of them just data.

`Presto` can search data from them once time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean that you have multiple Hive installations (HDFS + Hive Metastore), yes you can access all of them from a single Presto query.  Simply, add a hive catalog file (with a different name) for each cluster.  See https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html for more information on setting up connections to hive.